# The results lack some numbers

Tags: python

when I type the number to 1 from 120. the result is missing some number like: 21, 27,...

```
import math
j=[] #list

intInputA=int(input("Nhập khoảng bắt đầu: "))
intInputB=int(input("Nhập khoảng dừng: "))
print("The numbers between",intInputA,"and",intInputB,"are:")

if(intInputA>intInputB):
    print("Sai dữ liệu rồi cậu! ")
else:
    for i in range(intInputA, intInputB + 1): 
        if(i%3==0): 
            a = math.sqrt(i) 
            if(a * a != i): 
                j.append(str(i))
print(','.join(j))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: There should be no numbers in j in that case. Because first, it sets a to the square root of i, but then only appends i to j if a != the square root of i.

Comment: @Hari, I tried to find the result which is divided by 3 as well as is square number. And I get the result lack some number like 21, 27, 30, ...

Comment: @Goyo. 21 is not a square number. I want to print the number which is %3 ==0 and IS NOT a square number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change a bit for my code. I convert code from float(for sqrt) to int. And the code is ok.

```
import math
j=[] #list

intInputA=int(input("Nhập khoảng bắt đầu: "))
intInputB=int(input("Nhập khoảng dừng: "))
print("The numbers between",intInputA,"and",intInputB,"are:")

if(intInputA>intInputB):
    print("Sai dữ liệu rồi cậu! ")
else:
    for i in range(intInputA, intInputB + 1):
        if(i%3==0): 
            a = int(math.sqrt(i)) 
            if(a * a != i): 
                j.append(str(i))
print(','.join(j))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JwRr.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your method doesn't work as expected, but you can try this:

```
import math
j=[] #list

intInputA=int(input("Nhập khoảng bắt đầu: "))
intInputB=int(input("Nhập khoảng dừng: "))
print("The numbers between",intInputA,"and",intInputB,"are:")

if(intInputA>intInputB):
    print("Sai dữ liệu rồi cậu! ")
else:
    for i in range(intInputA, intInputB + 1):
        if(i%3==0):
            a = math.sqrt(i)
            if(math.pow(i,2) != i) and (int(a+0.5) ** 2 != i):
                j.append(str(i))
print(','.join(j))
```

This prints out:

```
    ('The numbers between', 1, 'and', 120, 'are:')
3,6,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60,63,66,69,72,75,78,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,114,117,120
```

Note the change here : `if(math.pow(i,2) != i) and (int(a+0.5) ** 2 != i)`

Comment: But I don't want print the number which is square number like: 9, 25, 36,...

Comment: @cuteShit, I had edited the answer. You need to add another checking to identify a perfect square number